# Reading code from external file in tcolorbox and getting pdflatex> ! paragraph ended before \tcb@set@label was complete

Tags: listings, environments, tcolorbox, listingsutf8

I want to read code from external file in `tcolorbox` in new defined `\texexptitled` environment but could not succeeded (See MWE). Without this my MWE also throws two other errors `pdflatex> !  paragraph ended before \tcb@set@label was complete.`. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

### MWE

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{exampleTest.tex}
   Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{filecontents*}


%Definition of New Environments
\tcbset{
texexp/.style={colframe=green!85!black, colback=red!5!white,
coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!black, left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}},
fonttitle=\small\textsc\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small},
example/.style 2 args={texexp,
title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}


\newtcblisting{texexp}[1]{texexp,#1}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{texexptitled}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=texexptitled]{texexptitledspec}[3][]{%
example={#2}{#3},#1}


\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}


\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}
\begin{document}

% Redefine the document environment within a group

\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\tcbinputlisting{%
  listing file=exampleTest.tex
, colback=red!5!white
, colframe=red!25
, left=6mm
, listing options={style=tcblatex, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}
 }

\endgroup

\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\begin{texexptitled}{Example}

\begin{document}
Here, we use Example  with a title line.
\end{document}

\end{texexptitled}

\endgroup



\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\texexptitledinputlisting{% Just tried. Not Working.
  listing file=exampleTest.tex
, colback=red!5!white
, colframe=red!25
, left=6mm
, listing options={style=tcblatex, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}
 }

\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot the 2nd argument to, which is designed to hold the label for `\begin{texexptitled}{Example}{mylabel}`, according to the manual

Comment: You @ChristianHupfer are savior for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is still one error left, I try to figure out...

Comment: `\texexptitledinputlisting` is not defined. You have to use the `\newtcbinputlisting` command for that.

Comment: Other error is caused by undefined `\texexptitledinputlisting` environment. Looking for a command to read code from external file for `texexptitled` environment.

Comment: As I wrote before ;-) Best you just copy from the manual, e.g. current version on page 199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understood your intention completely. But, I corrected the errors Christian Hupfer already mentioned, and I made a new macro `\texexptitledinputlisting` which hopefully helps for your own extensions. I kept the rest unchanged with small exceptions / corrections.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{exampleTest.tex}
   Welcome to \LaTeX.
\end{filecontents*}


%Definition of New Environments
\tcbset{
  texexp/.style={colframe=green!85!black, colback=red!5!white,
  coltitle=red!50!yellow!3!black, left=6mm,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}},
  fonttitle=\small\scshape\bfseries, fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small},
  example/.style 2 args={texexp,title={Listing \thetcbcounter: #1},label={#2}},
}


\newtcblisting{texexp}[1]{texexp,#1}

\newtcblisting[auto counter,number within=section]{texexptitled}[3][]{%
  example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcolorbox[use counter from=texexptitled]{texexptitledspec}[3][]{%
  example={#2}{#3},#1}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter from=texexptitled]{\texexptitledinputlisting}[4][]{%
  example={#3}{#4},listing file=#2,#1}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}


\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}
\begin{document}

\section{Test}

% Redefine the document environment within a group

\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\tcbinputlisting{%
  listing file=exampleTest.tex, colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!25, left=6mm,
  listing options={style=tcblatex, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}
}

\endgroup

\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\begin{texexptitled}{Example}{examplelabel}
\begin{document}
Here, we use Example  with a title line.
\end{document}
\end{texexptitled}

\endgroup


\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\texexptitledinputlisting[
  colback=red!5!white,
  colframe=red!25,
  left=6mm,
  listing options={style=tcblatex, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}]%
  {exampleTest.tex}{Example title}{examplelabel2}

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image]